# Can bounties be refunded by the earner?

Tags: feature-request, support, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I refuse a bounty?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78070/can-i-refuse-a-bounty)

Usually I pop in and out of the front page, looking at the stuff there and posting a few answers before going off to do other things.

So, I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260303/user-interface-element-for-3-way-input-yes-no-dont-care) yesterday. I noticed it had a bounty but didn't really think of it. Thing is, today it was awarded, and suddenly now **I'm 200 points richer than I deserve to be**.

I want to **put the rep in question back where it belongs**. I don't need or want 200 extra points for a 15-point action. I'm guessing it's not possible, but I have to ask anyway - is it? I'm not desperate to be rid of it but I do want to give it back to the asker if it's not too much of a pain.

Comment: (Re)post a bounty of your own on the question for 200 rep and award it to who you think deserves it.

Comment: What a pointless question. Seriously. You scored the bounty, move on. Nobody really wants to hear your calls of *"I'm not worthy, I'm not worthy"*.

Comment: Upvoted this due to its being a well-written and useful Meta question, _not_ because I support the premise or want to see anything like this implemented.

Answer (score 4):

Click the "start a bounty" link below the comments.

Comment: That would be less than ideal. I would have to tell the question-asker to post a garbage answer just so I could award it (which I'm guessing would lead to a bit of "no u" in terms of who should get the points), and during the delay time the question would be back on the featured tab for no reason.

Comment: @Toomai: Find an answer of the asker's that you like and post a "Reward existing answer" bounty on that.

Comment: @Toomai Why would you want to give the reputation back to the asker?  He posted the bounty on the question so it would get a better answer.  Posting a new bounty is the best way to give it back.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way, short of paying it forward or finding a question of yours which the creator of the bounty has answered, to refund bounties.

To look at the bigger picture, why don't you think you deserve those points?  You posted a relevant link to Wikipedia, showed a screenshot of a popular implementation, and gave the authoritative name of the element.  Whether you were trying or not, you wrote a good answer.  Enjoy the bounty!

If you felt really generous, you could edit your answer to better solve the OP's problem (this question: [Tri-state Check box in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726096/tri-state-check-box-in-html) might help you...), but that's not necessary.